# check if defaultValue from ARM Templates exists

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

I'm currently trying to make some arm template validation, but i need to make a check for, if the parameters is having a default value assigned, otherwise i will need to give it a value for testing purposes.

Currently i'm getting the names and types this way.

```
$TemplateParameterNames = $TemplateJsonParameters | Get-Member -Type 
NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$TemplateParameters = @{}
$TemplateParameterNames | ForEach-Object { $TemplateParameters[$_] = 
$TemplateJsonContent.parameters.$_.type }
```

And an example of the template

```
  "environment": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "int"
},
  "TenantId": {
  "type": "string"
},
```

I'm fairly new to powershell and arm templates, so this might be way simpler than i imagine.

Cheers!

Comment: this looks pretty much right, i cant imagine a more straight forward way. you might look if `test-azurermresourcegroupdeployment` helps, but i doubt that

Comment: You can also convert parameters into array (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-array#parameters), and check the element you need.

Comment: Any of you knows how i would get the defaultValue? 
i tried similar ways as the way im getting the type and name, but i can't seem this to work since some of my parameters doesn't have a defaultValue and then breaks when it gets to one of those